# What's wrong with a sqlite method

Tags: ios, sqlite

This is the method I'm trying to use:

```
NSString *orario = [NSString new];
int idmed = 0;
fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt1=nil;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt2=nil;
sqlite3 *dbase;
NSString *database = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"med.sqlite"];
sqlite3_open([database UTF8String], &dbase);
const char *sql = "delete from orari where date(orario) <= date('now','-2 day','localtime')";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbase, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
sqlite3_step(stmt);
const char *sql1 = "select orario,idmedicina from orari where date(orario)=date('now','localtime') and forever = 1";
const char *sql2 = "insert into orari (orario,idmedicina,presa,forever) values (datetime('?','+1 day'),?,0,1)";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbase, sql1, -1, &stmt1, NULL);

while(sqlite3_step(stmt1) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    orario = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt1, 0)];
    idmed = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_int(stmt1, 1)] intValue];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbase, sql2, -1, &stmt2, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt2, 1, [orario UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt2, 2, idmed);
    sqlite3_step(stmt2);
}
sqlite3_close(dbase);
```

The 3 queries seem to me to be correct, but the last one does not insert any row.
The second one, gets one row, so the last one should work (and it does if I use it directly).
What do you think is wrong?

Comment: "and it does if I use it directly" - Can you explain what you mean by this? What did you do "directly" and how did you do that? Can you show the code you used to do it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code here:

```
const char *sql2 = "insert into orari (orario,idmedicina,presa,forever) values (datetime('?','+1 day'),?,0,1)";
```

you put quotes around your `?` (Where is says `values (datetime('?'` change it to `values (datetime(?`).
The resulting code should look like this:

```
const char *sql2 = "insert into orari (orario,idmedicina,presa,forever) values (datetime(?,'+1 day'),?,0,1)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have quotes around your `?`. This will attempt to parse a literal question mark character as a date time. If you want `?` to represent a parameter you must not surround it in quotes.

```
const char *sql2 = "... VALUES (datetime(?, '+1 day'), ?, 0, 1)";
                                         ^
```